# Find the point of shortest distance to multiple destinations in the graph

Tags: algorithm, search, graph, breadth-first-search

I have been practicing algorithm questions for interviews. I cam across this question and didn't know if I solved it in the most optimal way:

Given a graph with multiple destinations to reach to. Find the starting point where the sum of the travel distance to all destination is shortest.

I tried to solve it with performing breadth first search with every single point and search for the destinations. But this is just brute forcing. Is there a better solution to this or is there any other related materials to this?

Comment: You could base it on all-pairs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#All-pairs_shortest_paths), instead of multiple single source shortest paths, but for practical algorithms, I doubt if that does more than gain you a constant factor.

Comment: so all the edges in the graph have the same weight? So you are looking for something better than O(N*(N+M))? How many destinations do you have?

Answer (score -2):

This is called the "Travelling Salesman" problem.  Look here for an answer:

[TSP (Traveling Salesman Problem) solver Using GoogleMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525766/tsp-traveling-salesman-problem-solver-using-googlemap)

I always thought that these types of questions were easiest to answer by finding the center point of all points which would then make a weird looking circle.  All you should have to do then is to walk around the circle.  However, I was shown by one of the mathematicians at NASA that that isn't always the best route to take.  A very interesting discussion indeed. :-)

To further elucidate what Salvador Dali is talking about - here is a graph of what he is saying:
[image]

And here is what I am saying:

[image]

Remember - this is just random points.  Both start at the origin (0,0).

Now for the clincher.  BOTH the way Dali and the way I am saying things are nothing more than possible outcomes of the Travelling Salesman problem. In Dali's, the salesman just goes back to the origin (where ever you want to start from) and then the salesman travels out to the next point.  In mine, the salesman just goes to one point one time.  What the actual answer to this particular question is - is unknown. Or to put that another way - the best answer is not known.  Usually though, the salesman criss-crosses back and forth to achieve the best path unless all of the points are equi-distant to each other.

Comment: No this is not called TS problem.

Comment: @SalvadorDali - Yes it is.  The TSP has multiple destinations to reach. The answer to the TSP is to find the best path to go to all destinations that is the shortest and easiest. The poster's second paragraph says the same thing.  Notice he also tried the brute force method mentioned on the SO web page I posted.  So it is the same.  Just a different way of putting it.

Comment: no it is not. In TSP you need to find a path to cover all specified vertices (of the smallest sum). Here he needs to sum from v to v1 plus  v to v2 plus v to vn.

Comment: How can it be TSP, if it can  be solved with applying bfs n times? TSP is NP-hard and n times bfs has polynomial running time...

Comment: @SalvadorDali: You are saying he always starts from one vertex and goes out to each.  I took it to mean he wanted the shortest path starting from one vertex and then going to the next.  Thus - v->v1->v2.... Only the poster can say which he is trying to do.

Comment: @ead You did look at the link where it says "http://scrivna.com/blog/travelling-salesman-problem/ - Brute force PHP implementation guaranteed to get the optimal answer. Only suitable for a limited number of nodes."